# Android App Deploys to Device, But Cannot Open: "Permission Denied." Runs on Emulator

Tags: java, android, xml, admob

I have a simple timer app. It counts down the seconds until event X occurs, with onscreen timers.

I've deployed this app to my phone, a Droid Turbo running 6.0.1, and have had success running it before attempting to implement an AdMob addition for the experience of integrating it.

Despite the fact that it's almost foolproof, and the fact that I can get that application to run perfectly in an emulator, running both Lollipop and Marshmallow, it will not run on my device. It simply pops up a small bubble in the lower quarter of the screen saying "Permission denied." This does not occur on the emulators, which present expected behavior and output.

The manifest is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.examplename.example.appname">
<permission android:name="com.examplename.example.appname.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".appCountdown"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.examplename.example.appname.INTERNET">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


</manifest>
```

I assume that the hopefully obvious error will be here. I can install it, but it won't run, leaving my debugger waiting for ever.

Comment: i think you have to ask user permission first, there was a link which had something about this when i developed my app, give me i sec and i shall find the link

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html link to android developer site regarding your issue.

Comment: I do request the Internet permission in the Java, but the app doesn't even open to request anything. I thought the same thing, but it's possible that my requests don't cover the full span.